# Why does this Microsoft Graph request works for most users, but returns "Bad Request - Error in query syntax" for guest users?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Sometimes, I do a request to get the value of several fields for a given user.

Here is an example of such a request that works for a given user(the id corresponds to a user of type "Member"):
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/bba8407c-2f05-4e91-b27e-a207689a085f?$select=passwordProfile,aboutMe,accountEnabled,assignedLicenses,assignedPlans,birthday,businessPhones,city,companyName,country,department,displayName,givenName,hireDate,imAddresses,interests,jobTitle,mail,mailboxSettings,mailNickname,mobilePhone,mySite,officeLocation,onPremisesImmutableId,onPremisesLastSyncDateTime,onPremisesSecurityIdentifier,onPremisesSyncEnabled,passwordPolicies,pastProjects,postalCode,preferredLanguage,preferredName,provisionedPlans,proxyAddresses,responsibilities,schools,skills,state,streetAddress,surname,usageLocation,userPrincipalName,userType`

No problem here. But doing the same request for another user of type "Guest", I get an Http 400 (bad request). Here is a request that fails, even if the format is exactly the same:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/3e3fac9d-ad76-4f9a-b86c-b4691a524572?$select=passwordProfile,aboutMe,accountEnabled,assignedLicenses,assignedPlans,birthday,businessPhones,city,companyName,country,department,displayName,givenName,hireDate,imAddresses,interests,jobTitle,mail,mailboxSettings,mailNickname,mobilePhone,mySite,officeLocation,onPremisesImmutableId,onPremisesLastSyncDateTime,onPremisesSecurityIdentifier,onPremisesSyncEnabled,passwordPolicies,pastProjects,postalCode,preferredLanguage,preferredName,provisionedPlans,proxyAddresses,responsibilities,schools,skills,state,streetAddress,surname,usageLocation,userPrincipalName,userType`

So the request syntax is identical, the only part that changes is the user id. But the second one returns "Bad Request - Error in query syntax". What is going on here? Why can I not do that request for guest users?

I can reproduce this problem for any tenant. It never works for any guest user.

Request-id of the failing request: `49e80d99-5074-4404-900f-e1d14889bf2b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears that some of those properties are unavailable for guest users. If you want to fetch non-guest users, you can use `$filter` syntax such as `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=userType eq 'Member'`